How to dynamically set AWS credentials for S3 access in an Apache NiFi flow?
I am building a data flow in Apache NiFi that needs to dynamically handle AWS S3 credentials and buckets based on an incoming HTTPS request. Here's the use case:
An HTTPS request triggers the NiFi flow and provides:

AWS credentials (access key, secret key, and session token if needed).
(We need to pass credentials to avoid a super-user that can write everywhere and because different users can have different permissions on buckets)
The target S3 bucket where data will be written.

Using these credentials, the flow needs to:

Authenticate with AWS S3.
Make an HTTP request to external APIs.
Write the API response to the specified S3 bucket.

The issue is that the PutS3Object processor in NiFi does not seem to support dynamically setting AWS credentials.
The  AWS Credentials Provider Controller mandatory for that processor appears to be limited to static credentials. Is there a way to programmatically provide credentials to PutS3Object or an alternative approach to achieve this use case?
Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Hi, did you find a solution for this? I assume you are trying to use IAM Roles Anywhere service here.

We handled it using signed urls of s3. In this way the client generates an authenticated url  and it writes automatically in the right place @Shanga
